# Layering transparent images and text on top of a mapView (Swift)

Tags: swift, uilabel, mkmapview

I want to put a transparent box on top of a mapView and then some text on top of that.

I can do this treating the image as a button and altering the alpha setting but only the last UILabel I put in place remains black, the rest are muted.

Is this possible with Tags or something or does it have to be done programatically?

Anyway after a couple of hours sleuthing this is a working solution.

1. Declare your layer

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var layerView: UIView!
   var myLayer: CALayer {
       return layerView.layer
   }
   ```
2. Put a UIView on your ViewController and link it to layerView.
3. Create a method/func to display the frame, e.g.

   ```
   func displayMyFrame() {
        myLayer.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 40)
        myLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        myLayer.borderWidth = 1.0
        myLayer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        myLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        myLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        myLayer.shadowRadius = 10.0
       myLayer.opacity = 0.6
   }
   ```

   4. Put your UILabels on the view and change their tags to 1 (in this example).
   5. Call the func in viewDidLoad.

      displayMyFrame()
      view.layer.insertSublayer(myLayer, atIndex: 1)

The atIndex: 1 means that this frame will be put behind the UILabels with a Tag of 1.

This works, hope that it helps.

Comment: Code or image or something to help understand the problem please

Comment: Muted = dull/semi transparent, Tags are a feature of UIButtons and I was wondering if they could be used to sequence display order in some way. PhotoShop with an image has the ability to send an image to the back/front and back a level, forward a level. I was hoping there might be an equivalent here.

Comment: That's the issue. I'm trying to achieve this through the UI without code. I'll try and see where I get programmatically tomorrow and put the code up. Many thanks until then.

Comment: Have post code as requested in original question. Many thanks for your time.